# Print content only on even pages with notes on odd

Tags: external-files

I'm creating a series of student worksheets and want to simultaneously create an instructor's guide. Using the `multiaudience` package, creating content that only instructors see is straightforward. However, in the instructor version (IV), the spacing is much different than in the student version (SV), sometimes making it a bit difficult to find the content you want. (I.e., the bottom of SV pg 5 could be found at the top of IV pg 8).

So I'd like to make the IV as such:

1. All even pages are pages from the SV (so SV pg 1 would be IV pg 2, SV pg 2 would be IV pg 4, etc.), and
2. All odd pages would contain the notes that relate to the content on the related even page. (I.e., IV pg 3 would have notes on IV pg 2 ... which is SV pg 1.)

I have created some code that accomplishes this as long as the notes are very simple. But if the notes contain any math or formatting, things go awry. So in addition to the above two needs, I'd also like:

3. The instructor notes should be able to contain figures, tables & math and respect basic formatting commands.

I'm fine making it up to me to ensure the notes don't exceed a page.

Here's my code that works for small stuff: it writes the notes to an external file, which at shipout gets read back in. (I don't use `multiaudience` here as I'm trying to get the note-writing down correctly.) But it leaves much to be desired: the math isn't preserved, I can't use `emph`, etc., in a comment and line breaks/new lines are hard to create.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everyshi}

\newwrite\oppwrite
\immediate\openout\oppwrite=\jobname.opp

\newcommand{\comments}[1]{%
\immediate\write\oppwrite{#1}%
\immediate\write\oppwrite{}%
\AtNextShipout{\immediate\closeout\oppwrite%
\clearpage%
\input{\jobname.opp}%
\clearpage%
\immediate\openout\oppwrite=\jobname.opp%
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item. \comments{First comment}
\item Second \comments{Second comment}
\end{enumerate}

Here is content. \comments{This is a long comment with line breaks.

Be careful with these. And $x^2$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I applaud your sentiments for keeping one common file, however my simplistic approach would be to produce two well structured files (just watching page breaks) and use a very basic pdf manipulation to intersperse the odd pages. There are many command line tools out there that make that task a simple batch job even allowing for blank pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insertions, a system built into TeX mostly for footnotes and floats.

First you have to allocate a new insert with `\newinsert`. We will call it `\instructornoteinsert`:

```
\newinsert\instructornoteinsert
\skip\instructornoteinsert=0pt
\count\instructornoteinsert=0
\AtBeginDocument{\dimen\instructornoteinsert=\vsize}
```

The skip means that you do not have to reserve space on every page where comments are used. Also the `\count`  value `0` says that adding comments does not influence the space available for other content on the page, because the comments come on an independent page. Finally the `\dimen` ensures that the comment pages are not overfull. If too many comments are added they overflow onto the next page. Attention: At the end of the document you may loose comments if they do not fit on the comment page.

Now we patch the output routine:

```
\makeatletter
\output\expandafter{\the\output
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\instructornoteinsert\vfil}%
    \@outputpage
  \fi
}
```

After the normal output routine we check if there really was a new page (Then the page will have an even number).
Then a new `\@outputbox` is created, which contains all comments added to `\instructornoteinsert` during the page. (They are available in the box `\instructornoteinsert`)
Finally we output this box using `\@outputpage`. The advantage in using `\@outputpage` instead of `\shipout` directly is that the page layout is handled for us.

Now we just need to define `\comments` to actually fill `\instructornoteinsert` using `\insert`:

```
\newcommand{\comments}[1]{%
  \insert\instructornoteinsert{%
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty0
    \splittopskip0pt
    \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox
    \floatingpenalty0
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    #1%
    \@finalstrut\strutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

This mostly is identical to `\footnote`s. The fonts and paragraph settings are ignored to avoid external font instructions affecting the comments.
The penalties are important: With higher penalties we would risk affecting the layout on non-comment pages.

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newinsert\instructornoteinsert
\skip\instructornoteinsert=0pt
\AtBeginDocument{\dimen\instructornoteinsert=\vsize}
\count\instructornoteinsert=0

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\makeatletter
\output\expandafter{\the\output
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\instructornoteinsert\vfil}%
    \@outputpage
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\comments}[1]{%
  \insert\instructornoteinsert{%
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty0
    \splittopskip0pt
    \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox
    \floatingpenalty0
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    #1%
    \@finalstrut\strutbox
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item. \comments{First comment}
\item Second \comments{Second comment}
\end{enumerate}

Here is content. \comments{This is a long comment with line breaks.

Be careful with these. And $x^2$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does what I wanted. Wish I understood it better - your explanations are *very* helpful but when one starts messing with TeX at that low a level, I get lost.

Comment: @GregH I strongly recommending looking into the TeXbook, there you find a lot of details. Otherwise the best way to understand this is trial and error

Comment: I can ask this as a separate question, but maybe you can point me in the right direction or edit your answer: is there a way to turn the above on/off within a single document? As in, for a while, pages are printed as normal. Then I get to a section needing these comments and it is turned on (i.e., comments on odd pages). Later, I turn them off again. Ultimately, my issue is I don't know how to reset the `\output` routine to "default" settings.