# left side text, right side comment

Tags: books, double-sided, comments

I hope you can help me...

I would like to realize a project to typeset a book with LaTeX which satisfies the following properties.

Think of the opened book: On the left side of the two pages I would write regular text (maybe with line numbers) and on the right side there should be remarks and comments related to the text on the left side referenced to the line numbers.

Has anyone some experience with this kind of typesetting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's the *left right side* in a book?

Comment: Thank you! Excuse me, there was a mistake...i meant "right side" and corrected it

Comment: You could enlarge the outer margin, and use margin notes.

Comment: B.t.w., I wondered whether you meant the light or the reft side… ;o)

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but when I use margin notes I would have the comments and the regular text on one side. The regular text and the comments should be on two sides:

Page 1 Text
Page 2 comments to Page 1
Page 3 Text
Page 4 comments to Page 3
...

Comment: Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97369/how-to-make-a-long-table-split-on-even-odd-pages help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, but I think the longtable ist not the ideal solution...

Comment: @RobRTex, any news? Does any of answer solve of your problem? Instead to say "thank you" in comments you should upvote answers and the even accept one, which help you on the best way (by clicking on up-triangle and check mark at top left side of answers). BTW, so f you not accept any of received answers ....

Answer (score 2):

This is based on [Print odd and even pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455318/161015)

The `content` will always start on odd pages, with or without `comments`. No need to use `\newpage` or `\clearpage` to go to next odd page.

In the same way, the `comments` will go on even pages.

You have to fill page by page, alternating `content` and `comments` to keep them in sync.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}  

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455318/161015    
\newinsert\instructornoteinsert
\skip\instructornoteinsert=0pt
\AtBeginDocument{\dimen\instructornoteinsert=\vsize}
\count\instructornoteinsert=0

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\makeatletter
    \output\expandafter{\the\output
    \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\instructornoteinsert\vfil}%
    \@outputpage
    \fi
    }
    \newcommand{\comments}[1]{%
    \insert\instructornoteinsert{%
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty0
    \splittopskip0pt
    \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox
    \floatingpenalty0
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    #1%
    \@finalstrut\strutbox
    }%
    }
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Here is content 1, 2 and 3.}\bigskip
    
    1. \kant[1]
    
    2. \kant[2]
    
    3. \kant[3]
    
    
    \comments{\textbf{Long comment with line breaks to 1, 2 and 3.}\bigskip
    
    11. \kant[11] 
    
    12. \kant[12] 
    }
    
    \textbf{Here is more content: 4 and 5.}\bigskip
    
    4. \kant[4]
    
    5. \kant[5]
    
    \comments{\textbf{More long comment with line breaks to 4 and 5.}\bigskip
    
    13. \kant[13] 
    
    14. \kant[14] 
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a great idea!

Comment: Hello! Thank you Simon Dispa. I realized my project with this code! Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. At the end of the document I would restore the normal precedure (the text should be written on all pages). Do you have an idea, how to restore that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the \reledpar` package. This was originally designed for critical or bi-lingual documents where on even pages would be the text in the first language and on the adjacent odd pages the (same) text would be in the second language.

By suitable planning you could have your main text on the even pages and corresponding notes and comments on the adjacent facing pages.

Read the first 25 pages of the user manual to see what facilities it offers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `lineno`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{lineno}
\def\markref#1{\par\makebox[2em][r]{\lineref{#1})\quad}\hangindent2em}
\begin{document}

 (Odd page with nothing of interest)

\newpage % right even page for contents  

\linenumbers
\linelabel{foo}\lipsum[1]\par
\linelabel{bah}\lipsum[2][1-3]
\linelabel{baz}\lipsum[2][4-9]
\par\nolinenumbers

\newpage % Left odd page for comments 

\markref{foo}  This is a comment for {\em Lore ipsum}.  \lipsum[3][1-4]
\markref{bah} This is a remark about {\em Nam dui ligula}. lipsum[4][1-4]
\markref{baz}  This is a comment for {\em Donet aliquet}. \lipsum[5][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try!